# PASAR CAMPOS DE JAVA A UN API WEB

Tags: java

como puedo mandar datos a una **API**, desde Java!
he intentado con libreiras pero por alguna razon el api no los recibe

Comment: Hola @Blowerdow, te recomiendo hacer el tour en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, para saber como preguntar, para ayudarnos a ayudarte y evitar que te cierren la pregunta.

Comment: Bienvenido, revisa [ask], saludos,